# Copy all files except the last modified file to a new directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, last-modified

I need to move files from c:\prueba1 to c:\prueba99 but I don't know how to make a comparison betweeen all files in the source directory (c:\prueba99) to move all files in the directory with the exception of the last modified file in the directory. I know there is a wmic command with get InstallDate, LastModified, but I don't know the ms-dos syntaxis to asign a variable and compare it to know that one file readed is the last modified

I found an example:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic datafile where "drive = 'c:' and path='\\windows\\'"
   get LastModified^,Name /format:table^|find ":"^|sort /r') do @echo %%A
```

And tried to modify it with no result because it appears to just list the datafile names but not the files themselves.

This is my modified version:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A  in ('wmic datafile where "drive = 'c:' and path='\\prueba1\\'"
    get LastModified^,Name /format:table^|find ":"^| sort/r') do move (%%A) c:\prueba99
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /tw /o-d /a-d c:\prueba1\*.*'
) do move "c:\prueba1\%%a" "c:\prueba99"
```

`dir` command get the files in descending creation date order, so the first is the latest. `for` command iterates over this list, skipping the first one, moving the files to the target folder.

Comment: what does dir /b /tw /o-d /a-d mean?

Comment: @MethodistMX, only file names (`/b`), use the modification date on date sort (`/tw`), order by date descending (`/o-d`), do not include directories (`/a-d`)

Answer (score 0):

A way to ge the last modified file :

```
@echo off
set $path=c:\prueba99

for /f %%a in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d "%$path%"') do (
set $Last=%%a
goto:next)

:next
echo Last modified : [ %$Last% ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you and it also allows you to discard as many NEWEST files as you want (for your case I've taken 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: change the next two statements to match what you want
set srcdir=C:\prueba1
set tgtdir=C:\prueba99
if not exist %tgtdir%\*.* md %tgtdir%
set ctr=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%srcdir%" /o-d /b') do call :maybemove "%%a"
set /a ctr-=3
echo %~n0: %ctr% files were moved from %srcdir% to %tgtdir%
endlocal
goto :eof

::--------------------

:maybemove
:: increment counter and bypass the ONE newest file
set /a ctr+=1
if %ctr% leq 1 goto :eof
:: remove the double-quotes from the front and back of the filename
set fn=%~1
:: perform the move
move /y "%srcdir%\%fn%" "%tgtdir%"
goto :eof
```